# XMPP Spring integration - Chat

Tags: spring-boot, xmpp, spring-integration, smack

I am new to XMPP, trying to create a server in spring-boot to listen and send message using XMPP, this is what I tried

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:int-xmpp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xmpp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xmpp
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xmpp/spring-integration-xmpp.xsd">

    <int-xmpp:xmpp-connection
        id="xmppConnection" 
        user="admin@192.168.1.201" 
        password="finatel123" 
        host="192.168.1.201"
        port="5222"/>

    <int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter 
        id="xmppInboundAdapter"
        channel="chatMessageListening" 
        xmpp-connection="xmppConnection"
        auto-startup="true"/>

    <int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter 
        id="outboundEventAdapter"
        channel="chatMessageSending"
        xmpp-connection="xmppConnection" 
        auto-startup="false">
        <poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
    </int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter>

</beans:beans>
```

ChatMessageListening.java

```
public class ChatMessageListening implements MessageChannel {

    @Override
    public boolean send(Message<?> message) {

        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();

        System.out.println("FROM    : "+headers.get(XmppHeaders.FROM));
        System.out.println("TO      : "+headers.get(XmppHeaders.TO));
        System.out.println("Time    : "+new Date((Long)headers.get("timestamp")));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean send(Message<?> message, long timeout) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

ChatMessageSending.java

```
public class ChatMessageSending implements PollableChannel {

    @Override
    public boolean send(Message<?> message) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean send(Message<?> message, long timeout) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> receive() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> receive(long timeout) {
            return null;
    }
}
```

Doing this configurations I'm able to receive the message at `ChatMessageListening.send()` method.

I tried to send message using,

```
MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
template.setSendTimeout(5000L);

Message<String> xmppOutboundMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello, XMPP!" )
    .setHeader(XmppHeaders.FROM, "admin@192.168.1.201")
    .setHeader(XmppHeaders.TO, "adminone@192.168.1.201")
    .setHeader(XmppHeaders.TYPE, "chat")
    .build();
template.setDefaultChannel(new ChatMessageSending());
template.send(xmppOutboundMsg);
```

But it is not sending to client but it receiving to the `ChatMessageSending`. Please guide me what I am doing wrong. What I have to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `MessageChannel` strange way.

Please, consider to revise your vision on the matter: 
[EIP definition](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageChannel.html) and Spring Integration [implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#overview-components-channel):

> Producers send Messages to a channel, and consumers receive Messages from a channel.

So, message channel can't be a `listener` and can't be something like `sending`.

You have to just declare a couple `<channel>` in your configuration and use an appropriate `<service-activator>` to process messages from the XMPP and some other to produce messages.

Yes, `MessagingTemplate` can be use for sending, but you have to point out to the proper `MessageChannel` bean where your `<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter>` will be subscriber.

Right now your `ChatMessageSending` has a void implementation and there is no any wiring with the target channel adapter.

There is an XMPP [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/xmpp) for you by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the XMPP sample link. I created separate channel and separate service-activator for both inbound-channel-adapter and outbound-channel-adapter to listen and send messages.